# Spring MVC with Spring Boot doesn't work with the Tomcat server of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I tried to follow Spring Getting Started Guide for "Serving Web Content with Spring MVC" which uses Spring Boot and Gradle in addition to Maven.
I installed Gradle plugins to Eclipse.

I want to run the application using the Tomcat server in Eclipse because of that I also followed "Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR" guide and changed the "build.gradle" file as mentioned in the guide. Basically, I added lines "apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'", "apply plugin: 'war'", configurations {providedRuntime}, and providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"); and changed jar settings to war settings. Here is the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

eclipse.project {
  natures 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.nature'
}

war {
    baseName = 'gs-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

I also added HelloWebXml class as they mention. Here is the class:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class HelloWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

In addition to these I needed to change pom.xml a little because it was complaining about Java SE 7 features. Added the lines below to the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
            <fork>true</fork>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The rest is the same as the getting started guide.

For building, I run

```
gradlew eclipseWtp
gradlew clean build
```

commands. After this the war file is created in build/libs folder of the project. If I copy the war file to my local Tomcat server and start the server, everything works as expected.

If I drag the project to the Tomcat server under the Servers tab (which is created using the same local Tomcat) and run the server, a ClassCastException is thrown with the complaint:
"**Cannot cast org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer**".

I checked the folder structure of the project in both of the deployment locations.
In the local (non-Eclipse) deployment location, after the server starts a folder with the name of the war file is created as expected. In the WEB-INF folder, there is a **lib-provided** directory. I checked the deployment location of the Tomcat of Eclipse, it didn't include a directory named lib-provided. I guess the problem is about this directory not being created but I couldn't find a solution.

I was already using Spring MVC, and I know how to create MVC projects with web.xml but I am new to Spring Boot. The Tomcat server of Eclipse runs my previous Spring MVC projects fine. So the problem is about the Spring Boot project.

I checked several related questions but they were not the same one as mine. I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have both a `pom.xml` and `build.gradle`. You now have 2 build systems competing over control. Either use maven or use gradle don't use both.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, this is a guide from Spring. I think they should know about how to build a Spring project better than me. I would prefer using just Maven, too, but I don't want to increase the number of things that can go wrong by digressing from what the guide says.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine that you are getting a clash with the `servlet-api` JARs. If you are developing with embedded Tomcat (creating a JAR) you need to include the `servlet-api` JAR on your classpath in the `compile` scope. When you are deploying to an existing Tomcat installation (creating a WAR) you must declare the `servlet-api` jar in `provided` scope, otherwise it will end up in `web-inf/lib` and cause conflicts with the version provided by your container.

Here is the POM from the sample Spring Boot WAR project:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional/pom.xml

Note how the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` uses the `provided` scope.

Comment: I tried many things including that. I changed pom.xml as you mentioned. The result was the same. Also, as I mentioned above, I can create a WAR and it works with the local Tomcat when I copy it to the Webapps directory. I just doesn't work with the Tomcat of Eclipse.

Comment: Also, I guess the changes made to build.gradle file is for making the servlet-api provided. As I mentioned, a "configurations" element and a providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat") element are added.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot does some special handling to allow executable WARs that run both embedded or in a container. Specific attention has to be payed to dependencies in `provided` scope since these might conflict with the container. The details are described [in the Spring Boot reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-war-file-structure). The reason your build works when deployed via a built WAR but not via Eclipse is that Eclipse WTP doesn't actually use Maven to perform the build, so a Maven build and a WTP build won't exactly match.

I'm working on addressing the same issue myself. What I plan to do is create a seperate 'dev' maven module specifically for this purpose, and use  tags to switch (some of) the `provided` entries to `runtime`.

Comment: Please post again if it works. I quit using Spring Boot for now.

Answer (score 0):

@meribald you can configure your pom.xml in that whay:

```
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging-profile>jar</packaging-profile>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging-profile>war</packaging-profile>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

and on the top of your pom.xml

```
<packaging>${packaging-profile}</packaging>
```

So, when you are developing you run you application as a Java Application, and maven will generate a jar file. When you want to package a war file to deploy on a server, you run on a maven command line

```
mvn -Pprod package
```

or in Eclipse run  as >> Maven Build ..., and put "package" on the goals field, and "prod" (without quotes) on profiles field.